# .authenticate method failing with rSpec Fabricator generated credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rspec

The test application I'm working in has standard `session[:user_id]=user.id` style authentication.  I'm using Fabricator to test the assignment of a `user.id` to the session hash.  When I use Fabricator, the `user.authenticate` method fails, but when I manually pass in the credentials without using Fabricator, the test passes successfully.

I've put a `binding.pry` in the session controller's create action, and I can definitely access both the email and password when I call them, and yet the "authenticate" function does fail.  Why is this?

Test:

```
it "assigns user.id to session hash" do
        johndoe=Fabricate(:user) 
        puts johndoe.email
        puts johndoe.password
        post :create, email: johndoe.email, password: johndoe.password
        expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(april.id)
end
```

Controller:

```
 def create
    binding.pry
    user=User.find_by(email:params["email"])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[params["password"]])
      session[:user_id]=user.id
      flash[:success]="You have successfully signed in."
      redirect_to videos_path
    else
      flash[:danger]="There was something wrong with your email address or password."
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `params[params["password"]]`. Try `params["password"]`.